# What is the variable format to reference Views field data in a Global PHP that resides in a footer/header?

Tags: 7, views

Currently its annoying to have to manually parse through the views results data by either doing a print_r() or a dsm() via devel. Does anyone know how to reference a field via PHP when you put in a Global PHP field in either the header or footer of the View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [image]

To reference a Views field result here's the format of the variable when using a PHP Global in the footer/header in a Views display:

```
$results[0]->field_**<FIELD NAME>**[0]['raw']['**<VARIES DEPENDING ON TYPE OF FIELD>**']
```

This is in reference to a taxonomy id (tid) reference:

```
$results[0]->field_field_device_type[0]['raw']['tid']
```

This is in reference to a text field called full_name:

```
$results[0]->field_field_full_name[0]['raw']['value']
```

The [0] represents each result row and the last array value usually changes depending on the field type (text,reference,image, etc.) So its better to dsm or print_r() if you really need to reference something that your not sure of.

Here's a sample output of the array structure so you can get an idea of how its laid out:

[image]

---

**Here's a better view of the array output of a view's result when you do a print_r() within the header. I had to apply this to another view and forgot how to reference the variables. So here's the full output when you do a print_r($result[0]->field_field_machine_type): (keep in mind it has to be "field_field" when you reference a field.**

```
     Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rendered] => Array
                (
                    [#markup] => Tablet
                    [#access] => 1
                )

            [raw] => Array
                (
                    [tid] => 105
                    [taxonomy_term] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [tid] => 105
                            [vid] => 9
                            [name] => Tablet
                            [description] => 
                            [format] => plain_text
                            [weight] => 0
                            [vocabulary_machine_name] => machine_type
                            [rdf_mapping] => Array
                                (
                                    [rdftype] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => skos:Concept
                                        )

                                    [name] => Array
                                        (
                                            [predicates] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => rdfs:label
                                                    [1] => skos:prefLabel
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [description] => Array
                                        (
                                            [predicates] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => skos:definition
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [vid] => Array
                                        (
                                            [predicates] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => skos:inScheme
                                                )

                                            [type] => rel
                                        )

                                    [parent] => Array
                                        (
                                            [predicates] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => skos:broader
                                                )

                                            [type] => rel
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```